# Javascript timer slows down when when repetitively updating DOM element inside setInterval()

Tags: javascript, html, dom, setinterval

I am creating an application that uses a timer to draw lines to several canvases while updating stats to `DIV`s. In order to create the smoothest animation possible I've had to set the `setInterval()` timer to the smallest delay possible, which from my understanding, is between 10-15 milliseconds across browsers.

The issue I am having is with the stopwatch that tracks the scenarios running time. The stopwatch itself works well enough as I have established using `console.log`, however, the `setInterval()` timer slows down when I try to update the DOM element. This has lead me to believe that in combination with the small timer tick delay there is a performance issue with the way I am updating the DOM element.

Code:

```
function draw() {

    var drawTimer = setInterval(drawStuffTest, 15);
    var timer = doc.getElementById('time'); 

    var milliseconds = 0;
    var seconds = 0;
    var minutes = 0;

    function updateTimer() {

        //clear the old elapsed time
        timer.innerHTML = "";

        milliseconds += 15;

        //increment seconds
        if (milliseconds >= 1000) {
            seconds++;
            milliseconds = 0;
        }

        //increment minutes
        if(seconds >= 60)
        {
            seconds = 0;
            minutes++;
        }

        //Pad minutes and seconds with leading zeroes if either is lest than 10
        var secondsString = ( seconds < 10 ? "0" : "" ) + seconds;
        var minutesString = ( minutes < 10 ? "0" : "" ) + minutes;

        var elapsedTime = minutesString + ":" + secondsString;

        /* The timer works fine when I just use console.log to display the 
           timer however once I add the following statement to update the DOM 
           element the timer slows down */

        //timer.innerHTML = elapsedTime;
        console.log(elapsedTime);
    }
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: `setInterval` was never made to be reliable and smooth. Use `Date.now()` to get the current time.

Comment: are you able to expand on your comment? I do not require actual time I simply need to track the running time of the application

Comment: Wouldn't `requestAnimationFrame` help here

Comment: http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/ & http://ejohn.org/blog/analyzing-timer-performance/ - there is no guarantee that the callback will be called in every 15 milliseconds... it just adds the method to the execution queue... the actual execution might be delayed based on the scheduled tasks

Comment: @CodeMonkey: But the "running time" is the actual time? Currently you're just measuring how often `updateTimer` was called, not *when* it was called.

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/s8xrowmq/1/ - I would recommend the solution that uses the `millis` and then will increase the timer to 500 milliseconds

Comment: oh I c. I am doing it the way I am doing it currently because I have events that have a duration. With each timer tick it increments a counter by the delay and is used to test when each event is finished (count >= event[0].duration). If I use date.now it wouldn't not be synced with the scenario elapsed time

Comment: There is no telling when a timer will be executed by a browsers event loop... you can only make an educated guess OR use an accurate measurement of time such as ArunPJohnny's solution.